# SvelteKit + Docker

Tags: docker, sveltekit

I'm a little bit stuck trying to dockerize a SvelteKit App and receive the following error when I'm trying to build using: docker build . -t svelteapp

**Any ideas?**

```
[stage-1 3/5] COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build:

failed to compute cache key: "/usr/src/app/build" not found: not found
```

**My DockerFile:**

```
FROM node:19-alpine as builder
RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY .env ./

COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pnpm run build

FROM node:19-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build .
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json .
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "--experimental-modules", "index.js"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Had to use import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node'; instead of adapter-auto....